# Finding particular Windows Media Player playlists by one song

Tags: windows-media-player, music

I have very large number of WMP playlists, many of which have been burned to cd, which are now aged/scratched. Is there an easy way to find the playlists that I need to reburn if I know one of the songs on that playlist? I tend to avoid putting the same song on more than one playlist if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

WMP playlists (`.wpl`) are just text files (more specifically, XML files) that can be opened up in a text editor and searched through like regular text files. They contain the file names of the songs in the playlist.

So if you know a word from the file name of a particular song, you can search the text contents of your playlists for that word to find the playlist containing the song.